# Android error copying database to devices

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm using [this](http://blog.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/) famous database helper and want to copy a database to a device. 
I have already filled and pushed the database to emulator through adb, and it works fine on emulator, but the app has difficulty copying the db to devices.

I have also created an `assets` folder and put the database there at `~/Shiny/app/src/main/assets/database/shiny.db`.

Here is my main activity:

Here is my app's specific variables in the `DataBaseHelper` helper class:

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DB_NAME = "shiny.db";
    private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.shinyapp.shiny/databases/";
    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
    private Context myContext;
```

And here is the onCreate method that calls the DataBaseHelper:

but I get this error:

```
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

          Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
          setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
          // Get a support ActionBar corresponding to this toolbar
          ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
          // Enable the Up button
          ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        myDB = new DataBaseHelper(this);

          try {
              myDB.createDataBase();
          } catch (IOException e) {
              throw new Error("Unable to create database");
          }

          try {

              myDB.openDataBase();

          }catch(SQLException sqle){

              throw new Error("Unable to open database");

          }
```

But I get this error:

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                            
java.lang.Error: Error copying database
at com.shinyapp.shiny.DataBaseHelper.createDataBase(DataBaseHelper.java:61)
at com.shinyapp.shiny.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:52)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1053)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1934)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:128)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I'm wondering what could be wrong here and how can I fix it?

UPDATE: here the error log that I get when I modified error handling to log the error instead of just throwing errors:

```
05-27 16:13:08.196 23913-23913/com.shinyshop.shiny E/SqliteDatabaseCpp: sqlite3_open_v2("/data/data/com.shinyshop.shiny/databases/shiny.db", &handle, 1, NULL) failed
05-27 16:13:08.204 23913-23913/com.shinyshop.shiny E/SQLiteDatabase: Failed to open the database. closing it.
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unable to open database file
app  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.dbopen(Native Method)
app  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1124)
app  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1075)
app  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1051)
app  at com.shinyshop.shiny.DataBaseHelper.checkDataBase(DataBaseHelper.java:78)
app  at com.shinyshop.shiny.DataBaseHelper.createDataBase(DataBaseHelper.java:45)
app  at com.shinyshop.shiny.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:49)
app  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
app  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1053)
app  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1934)
app  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995)
app  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:128)
app  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161)
app  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
app  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
app  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)
app  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
app  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
app  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
app  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
app  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)


05-27 16:13:08.360 23913-23913/com.shinyshop.shiny E/Creating DB ERROR: exception
app java.io.FileNotFoundException: shiny.db
app     at android.content.res.AssetManager.openAsset(Native Method)
app     at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:315)
app     at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:289)
app     at com.shinyshop.shiny.DataBaseHelper.copyDataBase(DataBaseHelper.java:103)
app     at com.shinyshop.shiny.DataBaseHelper.createDataBase(DataBaseHelper.java:57)
app     at com.shinyshop.shiny.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:49)
app     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
app     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1053)
app     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1934)
app     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995)
app     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:128)
app     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161)
app     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
app     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
app     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)
app     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
app     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
app     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
app     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
app     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use SQLiteAssetHelper for this?

Comment: When you catch an exception, **log the exception**, rather than throwing an `Error` and losing all the details of what went wrong.

Comment: @DanielK I prefer to a simple and evident solution, rather than trying to conform to a 3rd party package.

Comment: While that is a good point, @CommonsWare actually made a comment specifically referring to the article you linked, in a previous question with this problem, saying that is old and gives people trouble and he recommends `SQLiteAssetHelper`. CommonsWare is most definitely an Android bible, I have his book & it's great so I strongly urge to give `SQLiteAssetHelper` a try, nevertheless, log the exception so we can try to help.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for your tip. I uses `Log.e("Creating DB ERROR", "exception", e);` in the `createDataBase()` exception handling and updated my answer with the log.

Comment: @DanielK, according to the log, its clearly a `FileNotFoundException`. How can I remove this? Should I modify my DB_PATH I guess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample code that you are using is old and awful.

That being said, your problem is that the sample code is expecting your database to be in `~/Shiny/app/src/main/assets/shiny.db`, not `~/Shiny/app/src/main/assets/database/shiny.db`. If you want the asset in `~/Shiny/app/src/main/assets/database/shiny.db`, you would need to modify the `AssetManager` code to add the `database/` part to the value that you pass to `open()`.

Comment: Well the `DB_PATH` is really misleading in `DataBaseHelper` so yeah, definitely awful code. What's other awful things about this code? Nonetheless, as you said moving `shiny.db` to `~/Shiny/app/src/main/assets` make my database being available on the device. Many thanks. You saved my weekend!

Comment: @Karlom: Well, your names are not lining up (`naqi.db` vs. `shiny.db`), though I am not sure whether that code that you are using requires them to be the same or not.

Comment: I solved that glitch. please remove the last comment. Thanks.